# Why IN operator not working properly having floating-point values in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, in-operator

I was working with **MySQL Queries**. While working I am having problem with the queries containing IN operator. When IN is used with integer values it works properly. But when IN is used with floating-point values proper output is not coming. If WHERE clause is used to check two values with IN operator, in case of values with datatype float it only checks and returns the value which appears first in the table from the given values in query for few cases.
Why this occurs and how to solve this?

Let there is a table **customer** with attribute customer_id int(4)

---

| customer_id |
| --- |
| 3001 |
| 3003 |
| 3007 |
| 3008 |
| 3009 |
| 3012 |

Lets say there is query:

```
select customer_id from customer where customer_id in (3007,3008,3009);
```

[image: Output for above query:]
Here it works fine and outputs the records containing these values under the specified attribute

But when there are values of float datatype a problem occurs

There is a table **orders** with attribute purch_amt float(6,2)

| purch_amt |
| --- |
| 110.5 |
| 948.5 |
| 1983.43 |

If the query is:

```
select purch_amt from orders where purch_amt in(948.5,110.5);
```

[image: Output for above query:]
It returns the records from the table for this case.

If the query is:

```
select purch_amt from orders where purch_amt in(948.5,1983.43);
```

[image: Output for above query:]
It only returns the record containing the value which is present earlier in the table for this case.
Why is this occuring and how can we solve this?

Comment: Floating point is an approximation. Some floating point numbers that print the same are not actually identical, there can be extra fractional digits that aren't printed. You should never use it if you need to compare fractions exactly. If you're representing money, either use integers of pennies, or use `DECIMAL`

Comment: you would also not find a record with `purch_amt = 1983.43`, this isn't just a problem with IN.  You should almost never use floating point storage, and if you do, never check for equality and expect it to work all the time.  change your column to `decimal(6,2)`

Comment: I recommend you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: The software is not showing you the complete values of the floating-point data. For example, 1983.4300537109375 and 1983.43017578125 may both be shown as “1983.43”. When you ask it to find items with the value “1983.43”, it looks only for those with value 1983.4300537109375 and does not find those with value 1983.43017578125. If the software you are using has options to show the complete values, then use those. If it does not, then it is defective.